# arm_navigation package (lack of) scaling issue from urdf files

Tags: urdf, arm-navigation, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I tried getting the arm_navigation tool running with my custom (non-PR2) robot .urdf file and had some issues.  The biggest (literally) issue was that my .urdf file uses .stl mesh files that are in inches that are manually scaled to meters. For example:

0.0254, being the inches-to-meters scale factor.

Now this all works fine in rviz and gazebo and whatever, but when I run the arm_navigation stack, things go a little crazy---at least in the display.  I think the motion planner pieces are working fine, but if you run the planning_components_visualizer tool or the initial wizard to set things up, the green and pink overlays are at the original scale (and thus gigantic).

Anybody seen, or aware of this?

Thanks,
Steve

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12324/arm_navigation-package-(lack-of)-scaling-issue-from-urdf-files/) by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, I encountered the same problem.

[Relevant Bug Report](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/ticket/4629)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having this same issue. I had to convert my model from m to mm using scale:

```
scale=".001 .001 .001"
```

Any progress on this bug fix? Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2012-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-07**:
@Dave Coleman I suggest that you follow up on the ticket.